# How to tell if DocuSign envelope was wet signed via API

Tags: docusignapi

I am trying to determine if a DocuSign envelope was wet-signed (i.e. downloaded, signed, uploaded/faxed) after I receive the notification that it was signed. For my project, we need to review wet-signed contracts before processing.  I do not see a way in the REST API to determine this.  When I call /v2/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}/documents, it comes back with list of documents and it says signature type is "electronic" even though I wet-signed it when testing.  I am using a sandbox account, so that could be a factor.  Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Check the [Envelopes::listAuditEvents](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/reference/Envelopes/Envelopes/listAuditEvents) API method to see if it provides the information you need.